# why is my heroku postgres server lagging out?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm encountering an issue in uploading data to my postgres database with Heroku outside the app. It's not raising an exception, but it's essentially just stalling on the following command:

`df.to_sql(name=f'[MY_TABLE_NAME'], con=conn, if_exists='replace')`

where conn is initialised as follows:

```
os.environ['DATABASE_URL'] = f'postgresql://[MY_URL]'
if os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') is not None:
    ENGINE_PATH = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
    engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH)
    conn = engine.connect()
```

This code has worked before, and seems to occasionally work now but more often than not it's lagging out (eventually it gives a 'timed out' error). The `df` is only 10 rows with around 8 columns, so I'm not sure why it's struggling. Apparently you only get postgres logs with a $50 per month plan so I can't diagnose this issue further.

Comment: I'd use Wireshark to see what packets are exchanged and the timing of these packet.